# How to rewrite only one field (line[n]) in csv but in same time be able to work with data?

Tags: python, csv, csvreader, csvwriter

I have a csv file with three lines and three columns here.

[This is the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT1Pc.png)

At first I want to print all the lines.
Subsequently, for each of them, program check whether it is written in the second field(index 1) USA. If so, program will take the price from the third field and multiply it by two.

Now I need to rewrite this doubled price instead of 2000 (in line with the USA)

```
import csv

with open('countries.csv', 'r') as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source)
    writer = csv.writer(source)

    for line in reader: 
        print(*line, sep=';')

with open('countries.csv', 'r') as source: 
    reader = csv.reader(source)

    for line in reader:
        if line[2] == "USA":
            actual_price = int(line[2])
            print(actual_price)
            new_price = int(actual_price) * 2
            print(new_price)
```

Someone has already advised me to use the creation of a new file.
But this causes problems when I want to work with the data in the file first.

```
import csv
import os

  


with open('countries.csv', mode='r') as oldfile, open(
        'countries.tmp', mode='w', newline='') as newfile:
    # define a reader and a writer
    reader = csv.reader(oldfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
   
    for line in reader: 
       print(*line, sep=';')



    # copy everything changing the third field


    for line in reader:
        if line[2] == "USA":
            actual_price = int(line[2])
            print(actual_price)
            new_price = int(actual_price) * 2
            print(new_price)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], ,new_price])


# ok, time to rename the file
os.replace('countries.tmp', 'countries.csv')
```

Thank you for answer

Comment: There is a library called `pandas` that does all this. It's a little bit like Excel. Look it up and read a tutorial.

Comment: "this causes problems when I want to work with the data in the file first." What problems does it cause? What happens when you run your second program and what do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing `new_price` at every iteration of your `for` loop. You should therefore be writing the row within the loop where you change the value:

```
with open('countries.csv', mode='r') as oldfile, open('countries.tmp', mode='w', newline='') as newfile:
    reader = csv.reader(oldfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        price = int(row[2])
        if row[1] == "USA":
            price = price*2
        writer.writerow([row[0], row[1], price])

os.replace('countries.tmp', 'countries.csv')
```

Comment: In the output is _builtins.NameError: name 'row' is not defined_

Comment: Please copy-paste the above code exactly. I use `for row in reader`. You probably have `for line in reader`